# How do I pass multiple functions (with arguments attached) through a function and output them as a list of functions WITHOUT EXECUTING them

Tags: python, algorithm, function

As the title states, I'm trying to create a function that takes any number of functions as arguments (including their arguments). It will then take these functions and output them in a list ready to be executed, without executing any of them beforehand.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
def fxn1(name, employment_status="Working"):
    return name, employement_status

def fxn2(age, job=None):
    return age, job

def output_funcs(**funcs_with_args):
    uncalled_function_list = []
    for function in funcs_with_args:
        params_list = function.__code__.co_varnames
        function_args = []
        for parameter in range(len(params_list)):
            arg = funcs_with_args[function][parameter - 1]
            function_args.append(arg)
        uncalled_function_list.append(function(function_args))
    return uncalled_function_list

output_funcs(fxn1 = {"name" : "joe", "employment_status" : "coder"}, fxn2 = {"age" : 12, "job" : "farmer"})
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Ideally the output in this case should be:

`fxn1('joe', 'coder'), fxn2(12, 'farmer')`

**EDIT**

I've actually gotten the function to output correctly now but I can't call the functions since they are being outputted as strings (see code below):

```
def fxn1(name, employment_status ="Working"):
    print("hi")

def fxn2(age, job=None):
    print("hello")

def output_funcs(**funcs_with_args):
    uncalled_function_list = []
    for function in funcs_with_args["function_list"]:
        fxn_string = str(function).split(" ")
        fxn_name = fxn_string[1]
        params_list = function.__code__.co_varnames
        function_args = []
        for parameter in params_list:
            arg = funcs_with_args["args"][fxn_name][parameter]
            function_args.append(arg)
        uncalled_function_list.append(f"{function}({function_args[0]}, {function_args[1]})")
    return uncalled_function_list


funcs_yo = output_funcs(function_list = [fxn1, fxn2],
             args = {"fxn1" : {"name" : "joe",
                          "employment_status" : "coder"},
                     "fxn2" : {"age" : 12,
                          "job" : "farmer"}})

for func in funcs_yo:
    print(func)
```

Comment: Few things to notice, if params_list is list. You cannot use  for parameter in range(params_list):, the range() function requires int as input... and your function, I donot think you can have it called like fxn1 = {"name" : "joe", "employment_status" : "coder"}...

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus, woops that was a typo, should be `range(len(params_list))`

Comment: I agree on your point that the structuring is very weird like this. I'm just struggling to think of a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i'm understanding correctly, you probably want to use `functools.partial`.

I changed the input a little to accept any number of `(function, kwarg)` arguments.  If you are specifically passing in two parameters (fxn1, fxn2), you can use the kwargs assigment (where the type error was coming from).  In order to pass in an arbitrary number of functions, you need to use `*args` and not `**kwargs` in function_collector.

```
def function_collector(*func_kwarg_pairs):
    ready_to_call = []
    for func, kwargs in func_kwarg_pairs:
        new_function = partial(func, **kwargs)
        ready_to_call.append(new_function)
    return ready_to_call
    # as a one-line func: return [partial(func, *kwargs) for func, kwargs in func_kwarg_pairs]

# with your two funcs:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pairs = [(fxn1, {"name" : "joe", "employment_status" : "coder"}), (fxn2, {"age" : 12, "job" : "farmer"})]
    to_be_called = function_collector(*pairs)
    for item in to_be_called:
        item()
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have the correct idea but the code itself that you put isn't running correctly for me. Error: `TypeError: the first argument must be callable`